# How to display theta properly for Matlab to plot graph?

Tags: matlab

```
y=cos(\theta);
plot(y);
axis([-pi pi -1 1]);
```

I'm new to Matlab and am trying to display theta, this way doesn't work. How would I display theta in a trig function? I just created a simple version but I will need to apply it to a more complicated version once I understand how to apply it.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with mathematics and belongs on another site.

Comment: All math software except Mathematica is on-topic for this site.  (Mathematica has its own group.)  If you don't trust me, note the tag with 125 watchers and 2,700 questions.

Comment: Daryl's answer below is right.You can always find information (at least basic) about the functions of Matlab in its official webpage.

Answer (score 1):

The `plot` function accepts two parameters. You can use `plot(theta,y)` to have the angle on the $x-$axis and the function value on the $y-$axis.